# Can this sum convert to intergral

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, limits

The problem is to show $\lim_{n\to \infty} (\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2k}{n^2+n+k})^n = e^{-\frac{2}{3}}$.

RHS:
$\lim (\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2k}{n^2+n+k})^n =  e^{\sum_{k=1}^n n\ln(\frac{2k}{n^2+n+k})}$.
So we need just consider $ n\ln(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2k}{n^2+n+k})$, which can be convert to
$$n \ln(n\sum \frac{1}{n}\frac{\frac{2k}{n}}{n + 1 + \frac{k}{n}}).$$

Now, I want to convert the sum to integral
$$n \ln(n\sum \frac{1}{n}\frac{\frac{2k}{n}}{n + 1 + \frac{k}{n}}) = n \ln(n\int_0^1 \frac{2x}{n + 1 + x}dx).$$

I want to know if this conversion is valid. If so, how can we prove it.

Comment: The term containing $n$ shouldn't be left in the integrand, so this is not valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* do this, although the early conversion to ln(...) is something of a distraction. It is called the “trapezoidal rule” and says that for large $n$,
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n ~\frac1n~f\left({k\over n}\right) = \int_0^1 \mathrm dx~f(x) + \frac{f(0) + f(1)}{2n} + \frac{f''(\alpha)}{12 n^2}\tag{A}
$$ for some $0\le \alpha \le 1.$

The construction treats the $n+1$ points $x_k=k/n$ as a uniform partition of the area under the curve $f(x)$ in terms of $n$ trapezoids with area $$A_k = \frac1n\frac{f(x_k)+f(x_{k+1})}2,$$ each internal point gets counted twice so you get two halves, except that the first point and last point only get counted once and so only contribute one half to the sum, so to get the full sum of $n+1$ terms on the LHS of eq. (A) you have to add them also to the RHS. Then the error comes from the concavity of the curve, but as long as this second derivative is bounded it's just a $1/n^2$ error term.

Your target then needs to be the well-known limit that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac xn + O(n^{-2})\right)^n=e^x.
$$
As you can see this leading error term of $(f(0)+f(1))/(2n)$ is probably going to make a contribution here because it goes like 1/n, but other terms might not.

Answer (score 3):

Taking partial limits like that is not valid so we need to be more clever. Consider

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2k}{n^2+n+k} = \frac{1}{n^2+n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2k}{1+\frac{k}{n^2+n}} = \frac{1}{n^2+n}\sum_{k=1}^n 2k\left(1-\frac{k}{n^2+n} + \cdots\right)$$

$$= 1 - \frac{2n+1}{3n(n+1)} + \frac{1}{2n(n+1)} - O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right) \equiv S_n $$

by geometric series and the formulae for the sum of the first $n$ integers and their powers. We now also have

$$ 1 - \frac{2}{3n} = \leq S_n \leq 1 - \frac{2}{3n} + \frac{5}{6n(n+1)}$$

$$\left(1 - \frac{2}{3n} \right)^n \leq (S_n)^n \leq \left(1 - \frac{2}{3n} + \frac{5}{6n(n+1)}\right)^n$$

which implies

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(S_n)^n = \boxed{e^{-\frac{2}{3}}}$$

by squeeze theorem.